# Wanting a sliding reveal transition by bring in an image from the top of a page

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to create with CSS on chrome only, a transition that starts out with an image that is the full width of the body (whatever that is) and have that image slide down from the top (not skewed) and slowly push whatever is below it down.  That is, think of it like a baseball card being slide from above the screen down in front of the screen until it is its full height.  The HTML will basically look like this:

```
<body>
  <img id='myimage' class='myimageclass' src=.../>
  <div>... lots more stuff
  ...
</body>
```

I've tried varying the height but that just makes the image start 0x0 and slowly grow to full size. I'm hoping to somehow get it to fill the body width wise and just slide down until it's fully uncovered.

Here is my non-working css.

```
<style>
  .myimageclass {
    height: 0%;
  }
  .myimageclass.fadeIn {
    height: 100%;
    transition: 2.0s height;
  }
</style>
```

I have in my onReady something that just adds the class fadeIn to the image tag.

Comment: If you're adding `.fadeIn` with javascript, then is there any particular reason to avoid a javascript solution? Just curious :)

Comment: I prefer CSS since I know it's chrome and the CSS makes it really smooth and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSS animation to animate the `top` property of a container element, effectively sliding the entire content piece down the page while preserving the children's relative locations.

It isn't perfect, but it does have an image that scales to device width. It runs on Chrome, but you may want to add vendor prefixes to the `animation` property all the same.

Key to the animation running once is `animation-fill-mode: forwards`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.slide').addClass('slide-anim');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
}

.slide-anim {
  animation: slideDown 1s linear forwards;
}

.slide-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    top: -200px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="slide">
  <image class="slide-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200.jpg" />
  <div>
    hello page content
  </div>
</main>
```

Because you asked...

The animation works by offsetting page content by an amount equal to the height (display or inherent) of the image. The CSS `top` value specified should equal this height (I believe a positive `bottom` value would achieve the same effect). Here's a visual, where `x` = `top` offset AND the image height (black is `<html>` and blue is `<main>`):
[image]

If you know the image height, you can plug it in as a pixel value (in this case 200px because it fits nicely in the SO preview pane). If you know the amount of screen you'd like it to take up, you can use `vh`. If you don't know either of things, I'm sure there's a clever solution somewhere :)

Comment: Thanks @Frish.  You are an over-achiever but sadly, it's almost perfect and I'm struggling to get it what I need.  Two problems: 1) For reasons that don't fit here, I do need to use JavaScript to launch it and it needs to start hidden.  2) The image can't distort later if the browser is made narrower.  That is, if the browser gets thinner, the image needs to get shorter. I'll keep working on it based on what you have but if you have an idea, I'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, and also, I can't use background images, I need the image tag right after the body.  Short story is I'm building a chrome extension which is quite tricky for me.

Comment: Hmmm, you could use js to trigger the animation by isolating the animation to the class you add to the element. As for the image, you can use a unit other than `vh` or possibly media queries to get that effect. Also, I'm not sure how evident it is in the demo, but `background-size: cover;` should maintain image proportions (though perhaps `contain` may be better in some situations).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about the limitations of Chrome extensions -- consider updating your question with this fact, adding a tag, or both :)

Comment: OK, once more with image tag and js trigger

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the 200px.  is there any way to not have to specify the exact height of the image? I don't know that ahead of time and the CSS is static

Comment: I've added a bit to clarify where the 200px came from. I'm not sure CSS animation works if you want to support custom/a variety of image sizes, as to my knowledge you cannot animate height from something like 100% to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code but @frish really has it right

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .slide {
        position: relative;
        top: -50vh;
        animation: slideDown 4s linear forwards;
      }

      .slide-image {
        background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800x800.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        height: 50vh;
        width: 100vw;
      }

      @keyframes slideDown {
        from {
          top: -50vh;
        }
        to {
          top: 0;
        }
      }
    </style>

    <script type="application/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myimage").addClass("slideDown");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="slide">
      <div>
        <img src="stars.jpeg" class="slide-image" id="myimage" />
      </div>
      <hr />
      <br />
      <img src="stars.jpeg" />

  <span>text of page</span>
  </body>
</html>
```